# Encase a single or multiline search result PHP/regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to encase this string:

```
<p class="someclass">some text</p>
```

in a table tag like this:

```
<table class="anotherclass"><tr><td>
<p class="someclass">some text</p>
</td></tr></table>
```

it gets little more complicated as there could be one, two or three lines of code to be encased like this:

```
<table class="anotherclass"><tr><td>
<p class="someclass">some text</p>
<p class="someclass">more text</p>
<p class="someclass">another line of text</p>
</td></tr></table>
```

I have given my best using PHP with following code, but it does not work :/
$doc contains string code of a html document, first I count number of lines which I need to generate needed regex, im not sure if $& can be used to say: this is what I need to encase..

```
$line_count=substr_count($doc, '<p class="someclass">');

for($i=0;$i<$line_count;$i++)
{$add.='[^</p>]</p>';}

$regex='/<p class="someclass">'.$add.'/';
$replace='<table class="anotherclass"><tr><td>$&</td></tr></table>';
$doc=preg_replace($regex, $replace, $doc);
```

Am I even close to solution?

Comment: `$&` does not work. Neither does `[^</p>]` - that's still a character class, and not a negation. And the unescaped `/` in it will lead to an failure (at least enable `error_reporting` whenever something doesn't work).

Comment: Where does this table come from? Did you parse a document? Are you generating it?

Comment: What do you mean by encase? Are you trying to put the paragraph in the table, or are you trying to find it? What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: @mario: I have changed '[^</p>]</p>' to '[^<\/p>]<\/p>' now I dont have errors, but still nothing happens..

Comment: @didierc: i get document by reading htm file like this
$doc=fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
I am trying to find paragraphs with this same class and put it in one table. I was trying to find it with regex and open table tag before and close table after..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code - it will pick up one or more

blocks of "someclass"

```
$doc = '
<p class="someclass">Jerky tri-tip pancetta t-bone beef, meatball meatloaf flank brisket beef ribs biltong short ribs capicola fatback.</p>
<p class="someclass">Meatball short ribs venison leberkas shoulder meatloaf corned beef ham salami. Shank sirloin fatback flank pig spare ribs.</p>
<p class="someclass">Cow hamburger leberkas drumstick jerky beef short loin tenderloin swine pork. Kielbasa short loin jerky salami.</p>
';

$regex='/((<p class="someclass">(?:(?!(<\/p>)).*?)<\/p>\s*)+)/is';
$replace='<table class="anotherclass"><tr><td>$1</td></tr></table>';
$doc=preg_replace($regex, $replace, $doc);
```

Some comments:

((\s*)+) - ()+ will make it match 1 or more, \s* ensures spacing will be ignored between

and next

, external () is necessary to get all matched

blocks into $1 variable

/is - modifiers which make whole doc to be treated as a single string and ignore case. May be handy.

(?:(?!(</p>)).*?) - that's the main part - negative conditional match to ensure there is no

inside matched string

Comment: $regex='/((<p class="someclass">(?:(?!(<\/p>)).*?)<\/p>\s*)+)/is'; - needs another set of () to group them